# How to read a file from s3 using s3fs

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-s3fs

I have the following method in Python:

```
def read_file(self, bucket, table_name, file_name, format="csv"):
    data = None

    read_from_path = f"s3://{bucket}/{table_name}/{file_name}"

    try:
        fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(
            key=self.dwh_s3_client_key, secret=self.dwh_s3_client_secret
        )

        with fs.open(read_from_path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read()

        return data
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(
           f"Failed to read file {read_from_path} from S3 due to this error:\n`{str(e)}`"
        )
```

The problem is that I get an `Access Denied` error, but I'm able to read the files in the bucket, it fails only when attempting to read the content of one of the files.

Is what I am doing the right way to read a file from s3 using `s3fs`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permission issue to me. Could you please make sure the following Actions are added to your IAM role?

> ```
> {
>       "Action": [
>         "s3:DeleteObject",
>         "s3:GetObject",
>         "s3:PutObject",
>         "s3:PutObjectAcl"
>       ],
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
>     }
> ```